# Bound for singular value of the difference of two positive semidefinite matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, singular-values

Let $A$ and $B$ two positive semidefinite $n$-by-$n$ matrices. I am interested if I can bound
$$
\sigma_1 (A-B),
$$
the largest singular value of $A-B$, by a function (only) of $\lambda_1(A)-\lambda_1(B)$, $\dots$, $\lambda_n(A)-\lambda_n(B)$, where $\lambda_k (A)$ is the $k$th largest eigenvalue of $A$. I can derive the following bound
$$
\sigma_1(A-B) \leq \max \{|\lambda_1(A) - \lambda_n(B)|, |\lambda_n(A) - \lambda_1(B)| \}.
$$

I think this is possible if $A$ and $B$ are simultaneously diagonalizable and the two can be ordered with respect to the Loewner partial ordering, but I'm wondering if there are weaker conditions that make this possible. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: It turns out that my question was not clear at all. I meant to say that, while I do know that the bound
$$
\sigma_1(A-B) \leq \max \{|\lambda_1(A) - \lambda_n(B)|, |\lambda_n(A) - \lambda_1(B)| \}.
$$
holds, I was wondering if there is a bound that depends only on $\lambda_1(A)-\lambda_1(B)$, $\dots$, $\lambda_n(A)-\lambda_n(B)$. Thanks again.

Comment: By your definition, are positive semidefinite matrices necessarily symmetric/Hermitian?

Comment: When you say *"I think this is possible if $A$ and $B$ are simultaneously diagonalizable and the two can be ordered with respect to the Loewner partial ordering,"* it is unclear what "this" refers to. Are you saying that the bound you provided necessarily holds if $A,B$ are simultaneously diagonalizable? Are you saying that (you think that) it is possible to come up with a better bound in the case that $A,B$ are simultaneously diagonalizable? Please clarify what you mean.

Comment: @BenGrossmann I'll take them to be real symmetric matrices. By "this," I meant that $\sigma_1(A-B)$ can be bounded by a function of $(\lambda_j(A) - \lambda_j(B))_{j=1}^n$. Hope this clarifies. Sorry for being a bit unclear!

Comment: So when you say "I can derive the following bound"... if you have a bound already, then what is the point of your question?

Comment: @BenGrossmann The bound is not in the form I want. I was wondering if there's a bound that depends (only) on $(\lambda_j(A) - \lambda_j(B))_{j=1}^n$. The bound I wrote above depends, for example, on $\lambda_1(A) - \lambda_n(B)$ which is not in the form of $\lambda_j(A) - \lambda_j(B)$. Thanks again.

Comment: Ok, I missed that both of the indices were $j$

Comment: If you have some kind of bound on the distance between the eigenvectors of $A$ and the eigenvectors of $B$ corresponding to each $\lambda_j$, then you could produce a more useful version of my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

We have the following (not very good) bound. Let $\|A\| = \sigma_1(A)$. Let $\alpha_j = \lambda_j(A)$ and $\beta_j = \lambda_j(B)$. Let $x_j$ denote a unit eigenvector of $A$ associated with $\alpha_j$, and let $y_j$ denote a unit eigenvector of $B$ associated with $\beta_j$.  We note that
$$
A = \sum_j \alpha_j x_jx_j^T, \quad B = \sum_j \beta_j y_jy_j^T.
$$
We note that
$$
\alpha_j x_jx_j^T - \beta_j y_jy_j^T = \alpha_j(x_jx_j^T - y_j y_j^T) + (\alpha_j - \beta_j)y_jy_j^T.
$$
We find that
$$
x_jx_j^T - y_jy_j^T = \pmatrix{x_j & -y_j}\pmatrix{x_j & y_j}^T,\\
M_j = \pmatrix{x_j & y_j}^T\pmatrix{x_j & -y_j} = \pmatrix{x_j^Tx_j & -x_j^Ty_j\\y_j^Tx & -y_j^Ty_j} = \pmatrix{1 & -x_j^Ty_j\\x_j^Ty_j & -1}.
$$
The the non-zero eigenvalues of $x_jx_j^T - y_jy_j^T$ are the eigenvalues of $M_j$, which are $\pm \sqrt{1 - (x_j^Ty_j)^2}$. It follows that
$$
\|x_jx_j^T - y_jy_j^T\| = \sqrt{1 - (x_j^Ty_j)^2} \leq 1.
$$
Putting things together, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\|A - B\| &= \left\|\sum_j (\alpha_j x_jx_j^T - \beta_j y_jy_j^T) \right\|
\\ &= \left\|\sum_j \alpha_j(x_jx_j^T - y_j y_j^T) + (\alpha_j - \beta_j)y_jy_j^T \right\|
\\ & \leq 
\sum_j (\alpha_j\|x_jx_j^T - y_j y_j^T\| + |\alpha_j - \beta_j|\cdot \|y_jy_j^T\|)
\\ & = 
\sum_j (\alpha_j\|x_jx_j^T - y_j y_j^T\| + |\alpha_j - \beta_j|)
\\ & \leq 
\sum_j (\alpha_j + |\alpha_j - \beta_j|) = \operatorname{trace}(A) + \sum_{j}|\lambda_j(A) - \lambda_j(B)|.
\end{align}
$$

---

A possible slight improvement: we have
$$
\alpha x_jx_j^T - \beta y_jy_j^T = \pmatrix{\alpha x_j & -\beta y_j}\pmatrix{x_j & y_j}^T,\\
P_j = \pmatrix{x_j & y_j}^T\pmatrix{\alpha x_j & -\beta y_j} = \pmatrix{\alpha x_j^Tx_j & -\beta x_j^Ty_j\\ \alpha y_j^Tx & -\beta y_j^Ty_j} = \pmatrix{\alpha & -\beta x_j^Ty_j\\ \alpha x_j^Ty_j & -\beta}.
$$
The eigenvalues of this matrix are the solutions to
$$
\lambda^2 - (\alpha - \beta)\lambda - \alpha \beta(1 - (x_j^Ty_j)^2) \implies\\
\lambda = \frac{(\alpha - \beta) \pm \sqrt{(\alpha - \beta)^2 + 4\alpha \beta (1 - (x_j^Ty_j^T)^2)}}{2}.
$$
Suppose that $\alpha > \beta$. We have
$$
\sqrt{(\alpha - \beta)^2 + 4\alpha \beta (1 - (x_j^Ty_j^T)^2)} = 
\sqrt{(\alpha + \beta)^2 - 4 \alpha \beta (x_j^Ty_j)^2} \leq 
\sqrt{(\alpha + \beta)^2} = \alpha + \beta,
$$
so that the maximal eigenvalue (and hence singular value) of $\alpha_j x_jx_j^T - \beta_j y_jy_j^T$ is $\max\{\alpha_j,\beta_j\}$.